# Why can't I use a splat operator here instead of self?

Tags: ruby

Here's what works:

```
def sum
  result = 0
  self.each { |num| result += num }
  result
end
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
def sum(*numbers)
  result = 0
  numbers.each { |num| result += num }
  result
end
```

Test: pass in [4,6,9], should get the sum.  Top function works, bottom function doesn't add them.

Messing around and it turns out that `self.` isn't necessary to keep the tests passing.  Is it just good form?

Comment: @sawa woops, copy-paste didn't quite get everything the first time.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def sum(*numbers)
    result = 0
    numbers.each { |num| result += num }
    result
  end
  p sum(1,2,3)
```

or

```
class Array
def sum
    result = 0
    self.each { |num| result += num }
    result
end
end
p ([1,2,3].sum)
```

Output:

```
6
```

Don't do the below:

```
  def sum(*numbers)
    p numbers
    result = 0
    numbers.each { |num| result += num }
    result
  end
  p sum([1,2,3])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
true.rb:255:in `+': Array can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
    from true.rb:255:in `block in sum'
    from true.rb:255:in `each'
    from true.rb:255:in `sum'
    from true.rb:258:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `numbers` argument takes all passing arguments to this method as an array.

But then you passing the one argument - the array, so you've got a nested array.

To fix this situation you can use flatten method to convert nested array to flat array.

```
def sum(*numbers)
  result = 0
  numbers.flatten.each { |num| result += num }
  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

When you use a splat to collect arguments, you are collecting them into an array. If you pass an array to a splat, you will get a nested array. For example:

```
def sum(*numbers)
  numbers.inspect
end
#=> [[4, 6, 9]]
```

In this case, [Array#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) will return `[4, 6, 9]` as its sole member.

### Solution

If you know you're going to be passing in an Array, you can use [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) instead. For example:

```
def sum array
  array.reduce :+
end

sum [4, 6, 9]
#=> 19
```

Comment: Ah, so is that the big difference between 'inject' and 'reduce'?  'reduce' will strip an array from the input whereas 'inject' simply iterates over the input?

Comment: @dresdin In Ruby, #inject and #reduce are synonyms. Use whichever one communicates your intent most clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this:

```
def sum(*numbers)
  numbers.flatten.reduce(:+)
end
```

This way you can invoke it both as `sum(1,2,3)` or `sum([1,2,3])`.